# Using REngine object multiple times

Tags: r.net

I run some R commands with R.NET from a C# trading simulation application.  When I run a first simulation everything works fine.  When I runa second simulation, it hangs.  The simulation app runs each simulation in a new app domain.  As I understand it, R.NET is run in only one app domain.  Is there a way ro fix this, as even the dispose method does not allow another initialization of the REngine object.

Comment: I did have a similar issue with R.NET. The only solution I found, was seperating my c# program into two processes. One main process and one running only the R.Net application. This process is a service. Then instead of restarting R I restarted the entire process.

Comment: Thanks.  Is it possible to post an example of the service process, and how to call it from the main process.  I am not really a programmer, rather a trader that self taught some c# programming.

Comment: apparantly I can't provide you an example as the application is used commercially. However, it took two developers about over a week to implement and establish the interprocess communication. So even if you integrate a smaller version I think that might be a bit advanced for a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use

```
using (engine = REngine.GetInstance())
{
  ...
}
```

because this would finally dispose the REngine instance and cause
the known RDotNet issue
"The single REngine instance has already been disposed of (i.e. shut down). Multiple engine restart is not possible."

Use instead:

```
var engine = REngine.GetInstance();
...
```

and do not dispose it!